# Payload from post request not available in node.js function

Tags: node.js, angularjs

I've just started to fiddle with three new (to me) frameworks/products: MongoDB, NodeJS and AngularJS.

What I'm trying to accomplish is to have a simple form submit a value and have that value written to the database. I've gotten to a point where my value is submitted using $http.post in my Angular app and I do get my node.js backend function called but my req parameter (se below) in undefined. From Google Chromes Network monitor I can see that a POST request is submitted and that the payload contains the value I've entered.

I really don't understand why it's not available in the receiving end. Please help.

Now for some snippets (not the entire files):

server.js:

```
var express = require('express'),
menu = require('./routes/menu'),
http = require('http'),
app = express(),
httpServer = http.createServer(app),
bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.set('port', 3000);

app.use(express.static(__dirname));

app.get('/menuItems', menu.getMenuItems);
app.post('/menuItems', function(req, res) { console.log(req); });

httpServer.listen(app.get('port'), function () {
    console.log("Express server listening on port %s.", httpServer.address().port);
});
```

menu.js:

```
exports.addMenuItem = function(req, res) {
var menuItem = req.body;  <===req.body is undefined
console.log('Adding menuItem: ' + JSON.stringify(menuItem)); 

db.collection('menuItems', function(err, collection) {
    collection.insert(menuItem, {safe:true}, function(err, result) {
        if (err) {
            res.send({'error':'An error has occurred'});
        } else {
            console.log('Success: ' + JSON.stringify(result[0]));
            res.send(result[0]);
        }
    });
});
```

};

app.js:

```
(function () {
var app = angular.module('jdk', []);
app.controller('MenuItemController', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.processForm = function () {
        $http.post('/menuItems', JSON.stringify($scope.formData))
            .success(function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            });
    };
});
})();
```

I think I've dome everything but apparently not. I also tried installing and using 'body-paarser' in my server.js but the result was the same.

When my server crashes it dumps something like this:

```
{ _readableState: 
   { highWaterMark: 16384,
     buffer: [],
     length: 0,
     pipes: null,
     pipesCount: 0,
     flowing: false,
     ended: false,
     endEmitted: false,
     reading: false,
     calledRead: false,
     sync: true,
     needReadable: false,
     emittedReadable: false,
     readableListening: false,
     objectMode: false,
     defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
     ranOut: false,
     awaitDrain: 0,
     readingMore: false,
     oldMode: false,
     decoder: null,
     encoding: null },
  readable: true,
  domain: null,
  _events: {},
  _maxListeners: 10,
  socket: 
   { _connecting: false,
     _handle: 
      { fd: null,
        writeQueueSize: 0,
        owner: [Circular],
        onread: [Function: onread],
        reading: true },
     _readableState: 
      { highWaterMark: 16384,
        buffer: [],
        length: 0,
        pipes: null,
        pipesCount: 0,
        flowing: false,
        ended: false,
        endEmitted: false,
        reading: true,
        calledRead: true,
        sync: false,
        needReadable: true,
        emittedReadable: false,
        readableListening: false,
        objectMode: false,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        ranOut: false,
        awaitDrain: 0,
        readingMore: false,
        oldMode: false,
        decoder: null,
        encoding: null },
     readable: true,
     domain: null,
     _events: 
      { end: [Object],
        finish: [Function: onSocketFinish],
        _socketEnd: [Function: onSocketEnd],
        drain: [Object],
        timeout: [Function],
        error: [Object],
        close: [Object] },
     _maxListeners: 10,
     _writableState: 
      { highWaterMark: 16384,
        objectMode: false,
        needDrain: false,
        ending: false,
        ended: false,
        finished: false,
        decodeStrings: false,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        length: 0,
        writing: false,
        sync: false,
        bufferProcessing: false,
        onwrite: [Function],
        writecb: null,
        writelen: 0,
        buffer: [],
        errorEmitted: false },
     writable: true,
     allowHalfOpen: true,
     onend: [Function],
     destroyed: false,
     bytesRead: 2496,
     _bytesDispatched: 157759,
     _pendingData: null,
     _pendingEncoding: '',
     server: 
      { domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _maxListeners: 10,
        _connections: 6,
        connections: [Getter/Setter],
        _handle: [Object],
        _usingSlaves: false,
        _slaves: [],
        allowHalfOpen: true,
        httpAllowHalfOpen: false,
        timeout: 120000,
        _connectionKey: '4:0.0.0.0:3000' },
     _idleTimeout: 120000,
     _idleNext: 
      { _connecting: false,
        _handle: [Object],
        _readableState: [Object],
        readable: true,
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _maxListeners: 10,
        _writableState: [Object],
        writable: true,
        allowHalfOpen: true,
        onend: [Function],
        destroyed: false,
        bytesRead: 375,
        _bytesDispatched: 1410,
        _pendingData: null,
        _pendingEncoding: '',
        server: [Object],
        _idleTimeout: 120000,
        _idleNext: [Object],
        _idlePrev: [Circular],
        _idleStart: 1406644394348,
        parser: [Object],
        ondata: [Function],
        _paused: false,
        _httpMessage: null },
     _idlePrev: { _idleNext: [Circular], _idlePrev: [Object] },
     _idleStart: 1406644399010,
     parser: 
      { _headers: [],
        _url: '',
        onHeaders: [Function: parserOnHeaders],
        onHeadersComplete: [Function: parserOnHeadersComplete],
        onBody: [Function: parserOnBody],
        onMessageComplete: [Function: parserOnMessageComplete],
        socket: [Circular],
        incoming: [Circular],
        maxHeaderPairs: 2000,
        onIncoming: [Function] },
     ondata: [Function],
     _paused: false,
     _httpMessage: 
      { domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _maxListeners: 10,
        output: [],
        outputEncodings: [],
        writable: true,
        _last: false,
        chunkedEncoding: false,
        shouldKeepAlive: true,
        useChunkedEncodingByDefault: true,
        sendDate: true,
        _headerSent: false,
        _header: '',
        _hasBody: true,
        _trailer: '',
        finished: false,
        _hangupClose: false,
        socket: [Circular],
        connection: [Circular],
        _headers: [Object],
        _headerNames: [Object],
        req: [Circular],
        locals: {} } },
  connection: 
   { _connecting: false,
     _handle: 
      { fd: null,
        writeQueueSize: 0,
        owner: [Circular],
        onread: [Function: onread],
        reading: true },
     _readableState: 
      { highWaterMark: 16384,
        buffer: [],
        length: 0,
        pipes: null,
        pipesCount: 0,
        flowing: false,
        ended: false,
        endEmitted: false,
        reading: true,
        calledRead: true,
        sync: false,
        needReadable: true,
        emittedReadable: false,
        readableListening: false,
        objectMode: false,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        ranOut: false,
        awaitDrain: 0,
        readingMore: false,
        oldMode: false,
        decoder: null,
        encoding: null },
     readable: true,
     domain: null,
     _events: 
      { end: [Object],
        finish: [Function: onSocketFinish],
        _socketEnd: [Function: onSocketEnd],
        drain: [Object],
        timeout: [Function],
        error: [Object],
        close: [Object] },
     _maxListeners: 10,
     _writableState: 
      { highWaterMark: 16384,
        objectMode: false,
        needDrain: false,
        ending: false,
        ended: false,
        finished: false,
        decodeStrings: false,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        length: 0,
        writing: false,
        sync: false,
        bufferProcessing: false,
        onwrite: [Function],
        writecb: null,
        writelen: 0,
        buffer: [],
        errorEmitted: false },
     writable: true,
     allowHalfOpen: true,
     onend: [Function],
     destroyed: false,
     bytesRead: 2496,
     _bytesDispatched: 157759,
     _pendingData: null,
     _pendingEncoding: '',
     server: 
      { domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _maxListeners: 10,
        _connections: 6,
        connections: [Getter/Setter],
        _handle: [Object],
        _usingSlaves: false,
        _slaves: [],
        allowHalfOpen: true,
        httpAllowHalfOpen: false,
        timeout: 120000,
        _connectionKey: '4:0.0.0.0:3000' },
     _idleTimeout: 120000,
     _idleNext: 
      { _connecting: false,
        _handle: [Object],
        _readableState: [Object],
        readable: true,
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _maxListeners: 10,
        _writableState: [Object],
        writable: true,
        allowHalfOpen: true,
        onend: [Function],
        destroyed: false,
        bytesRead: 375,
        _bytesDispatched: 1410,
        _pendingData: null,
        _pendingEncoding: '',
        server: [Object],
        _idleTimeout: 120000,
        _idleNext: [Object],
        _idlePrev: [Circular],
        _idleStart: 1406644394348,
        parser: [Object],
        ondata: [Function],
        _paused: false,
        _httpMessage: null },
     _idlePrev: { _idleNext: [Circular], _idlePrev: [Object] },
     _idleStart: 1406644399010,
     parser: 
      { _headers: [],
        _url: '',
        onHeaders: [Function: parserOnHeaders],
        onHeadersComplete: [Function: parserOnHeadersComplete],
        onBody: [Function: parserOnBody],
        onMessageComplete: [Function: parserOnMessageComplete],
        socket: [Circular],
        incoming: [Circular],
        maxHeaderPairs: 2000,
        onIncoming: [Function] },
     ondata: [Function],
     _paused: false,
     _httpMessage: 
      { domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _maxListeners: 10,
        output: [],
        outputEncodings: [],
        writable: true,
        _last: false,
        chunkedEncoding: false,
        shouldKeepAlive: true,
        useChunkedEncodingByDefault: true,
        sendDate: true,
        _headerSent: false,
        _header: '',
        _hasBody: true,
        _trailer: '',
        finished: false,
        _hangupClose: false,
        socket: [Circular],
        connection: [Circular],
        _headers: [Object],
        _headerNames: [Object],
        req: [Circular],
        locals: {} } },
  httpVersion: '1.1',
  complete: false,
  headers: 
   { host: 'localhost:3000',
     connection: 'keep-alive',
     'content-length': '19',
     accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
     origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
     'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.125 Safari/537.36',
     'content-type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
     referer: 'http://localhost:3000/admin/',
     'accept-encoding': 'gzip,deflate,sdch',
     'accept-language': 'en,da;q=0.8,nb;q=0.6,sv;q=0.4' },
  trailers: {},
  _pendings: [],
  _pendingIndex: 0,
  url: '/menuItems',
  method: 'POST',
  statusCode: null,
  client: 
   { _connecting: false,
     _handle: 
      { fd: null,
        writeQueueSize: 0,
        owner: [Circular],
        onread: [Function: onread],
        reading: true },
     _readableState: 
      { highWaterMark: 16384,
        buffer: [],
        length: 0,
        pipes: null,
        pipesCount: 0,
        flowing: false,
        ended: false,
        endEmitted: false,
        reading: true,
        calledRead: true,
        sync: false,
        needReadable: true,
        emittedReadable: false,
        readableListening: false,
        objectMode: false,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        ranOut: false,
        awaitDrain: 0,
        readingMore: false,
        oldMode: false,
        decoder: null,
        encoding: null },
     readable: true,
     domain: null,
     _events: 
      { end: [Object],
        finish: [Function: onSocketFinish],
        _socketEnd: [Function: onSocketEnd],
        drain: [Object],
        timeout: [Function],
        error: [Object],
        close: [Object] },
     _maxListeners: 10,
     _writableState: 
      { highWaterMark: 16384,
        objectMode: false,
        needDrain: false,
        ending: false,
        ended: false,
        finished: false,
        decodeStrings: false,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        length: 0,
        writing: false,
        sync: false,
        bufferProcessing: false,
        onwrite: [Function],
        writecb: null,
        writelen: 0,
        buffer: [],
        errorEmitted: false },
     writable: true,
     allowHalfOpen: true,
     onend: [Function],
     destroyed: false,
     bytesRead: 2496,
     _bytesDispatched: 157759,
     _pendingData: null,
     _pendingEncoding: '',
     server: 
      { domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _maxListeners: 10,
        _connections: 6,
        connections: [Getter/Setter],
        _handle: [Object],
        _usingSlaves: false,
        _slaves: [],
        allowHalfOpen: true,
        httpAllowHalfOpen: false,
        timeout: 120000,
        _connectionKey: '4:0.0.0.0:3000' },
     _idleTimeout: 120000,
     _idleNext: 
      { _connecting: false,
        _handle: [Object],
        _readableState: [Object],
        readable: true,
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _maxListeners: 10,
        _writableState: [Object],
        writable: true,
        allowHalfOpen: true,
        onend: [Function],
        destroyed: false,
        bytesRead: 375,
        _bytesDispatched: 1410,
        _pendingData: null,
        _pendingEncoding: '',
        server: [Object],
        _idleTimeout: 120000,
        _idleNext: [Object],
        _idlePrev: [Circular],
        _idleStart: 1406644394348,
        parser: [Object],
        ondata: [Function],
        _paused: false,
        _httpMessage: null },
     _idlePrev: { _idleNext: [Circular], _idlePrev: [Object] },
     _idleStart: 1406644399010,
     parser: 
      { _headers: [],
        _url: '',
        onHeaders: [Function: parserOnHeaders],
        onHeadersComplete: [Function: parserOnHeadersComplete],
        onBody: [Function: parserOnBody],
        onMessageComplete: [Function: parserOnMessageComplete],
        socket: [Circular],
        incoming: [Circular],
        maxHeaderPairs: 2000,
        onIncoming: [Function] },
     ondata: [Function],
     _paused: false,
     _httpMessage: 
      { domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _maxListeners: 10,
        output: [],
        outputEncodings: [],
        writable: true,
        _last: false,
        chunkedEncoding: false,
        shouldKeepAlive: true,
        useChunkedEncodingByDefault: true,
        sendDate: true,
        _headerSent: false,
        _header: '',
        _hasBody: true,
        _trailer: '',
        finished: false,
        _hangupClose: false,
        socket: [Circular],
        connection: [Circular],
        _headers: [Object],
        _headerNames: [Object],
        req: [Circular],
        locals: {} } },
  _consuming: false,
  _dumped: false,
  httpVersionMajor: 1,
  httpVersionMinor: 1,
  upgrade: false,
  next: [Function: next],
  baseUrl: '',
  originalUrl: '/menuItems',
  _parsedUrl: 
   { protocol: null,
     slashes: null,
     auth: null,
     host: null,
     port: null,
     hostname: null,
     hash: null,
     search: null,
     query: null,
     pathname: '/menuItems',
     path: '/menuItems',
     href: '/menuItems' },
  params: {},
  query: {},
  res: 
   { domain: null,
     _events: { finish: [Function] },
     _maxListeners: 10,
     output: [],
     outputEncodings: [],
     writable: true,
     _last: false,
     chunkedEncoding: false,
     shouldKeepAlive: true,
     useChunkedEncodingByDefault: true,
     sendDate: true,
     _headerSent: false,
     _header: '',
     _hasBody: true,
     _trailer: '',
     finished: false,
     _hangupClose: false,
     socket: 
      { _connecting: false,
        _handle: [Object],
        _readableState: [Object],
        readable: true,
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _maxListeners: 10,
        _writableState: [Object],
        writable: true,
        allowHalfOpen: true,
        onend: [Function],
        destroyed: false,
        bytesRead: 2496,
        _bytesDispatched: 157759,
        _pendingData: null,
        _pendingEncoding: '',
        server: [Object],
        _idleTimeout: 120000,
        _idleNext: [Object],
        _idlePrev: [Object],
        _idleStart: 1406644399010,
        parser: [Object],
        ondata: [Function],
        _paused: false,
        _httpMessage: [Circular] },
     connection: 
      { _connecting: false,
        _handle: [Object],
        _readableState: [Object],
        readable: true,
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _maxListeners: 10,
        _writableState: [Object],
        writable: true,
        allowHalfOpen: true,
        onend: [Function],
        destroyed: false,
        bytesRead: 2496,
        _bytesDispatched: 157759,
        _pendingData: null,
        _pendingEncoding: '',
        server: [Object],
        _idleTimeout: 120000,
        _idleNext: [Object],
        _idlePrev: [Object],
        _idleStart: 1406644399010,
        parser: [Object],
        ondata: [Function],
        _paused: false,
        _httpMessage: [Circular] },
     _headers: { 'x-powered-by': 'Express' },
     _headerNames: { 'x-powered-by': 'X-Powered-By' },
     req: [Circular],
     locals: {} },
  route: 
   { path: '/menuItems',
     stack: [ [Object] ],
     methods: { post: true } } }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you need to use the https://www.npmjs.org/package/body-parser module to parse the body of POST request.

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname));
// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.get('/menuItems', menu.getMenuItems);
```

Comment: I tried that but req.body still came up undefined :-(

Comment: Where do you put the `app.use(bodyParser.json())` statement? It might be too late in the flow.

Comment: Second line in my server.js - will edit question... done

Comment: Tried this example: http://runnable.com/U0sU598vXio2uD-1/example-reading-form-input-with-express-4-0-and-body-parser-for-node-js and it works like a charm (body-parser depricated warning). Will study that.

Comment: Got it! Removed the http lines and just used app.listen()

Comment: Have spent couple of hours debugging dyson/express and finally was able to figure out that resulting JSON is accessible via `req.body`. I was expecting to get it in `req.params`.