# When using ExpressJS and body-parser req.body is empty

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, body-parser

```
var express    = require('express');
var app        = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

oracledb.autoCommit = true;

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

var port = process.env.PORT || 8090;

var router = express.Router();

router.use('/' , function(req, res , next) {
  console.log('Something is happening.');
  next();
})

router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.json({ message: 'hooray! welcome to our api!' });   
});

router.route('/insert')
    .post(function(req, res) {
      console.log(req.body);
      console.log(req.body.c1);
      console.log(req.body.c2);
    });


app.use('/api', router);

app.listen(port);
```

In the example above ,when I try to log `req.body` it is returned as empty along with any of its properties.

EDIT: Maybe unrelated but when I try to test this REST API with a extension like Postman , it just keeps processing indefinately. ( Same thing happens with extension called DHC Rest)

Comment: Be sure the type of content you're sending is of ContentType `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

Comment: yes, code is ok, your requests probably don't have a properly set ContentType

Comment: @ldebruijn How do I know which ContentType to use?

Comment: Can you add html into your question?

Comment: @Bonanza There's not HTML , I'm building a REST API. I'm testing it out with postman extension.

Comment: @VonD Where in this code would I set my ContentType?

Comment: I think you need to end the request. Throw in a `res.json({'somthing': 'random'})`, then it won't hang.

Comment: In Postman you have few options : form-data, x-www-form-urlencoded, raw, binary. Use x-www-form-urlencoded with key/value or raw with application/json header

Comment: @dcodesmith Thank you , that solved my problem if infinite processing!

Comment: @Bonanza thanks, it works now.

Comment: @Paran0a you set your ContentType on the request, not server-side. Where does the request come from ? a browser ? how do you build it ?

Comment: @Paran0a http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25019007/payload-from-post-request-not-available-in-node-js-function